# Interacting with other app

Tags: android

I created an app that launches Google Hangouts when a button is clicked.

Is there any way for the app to interact with Google Hangouts' UI? Such as click the first chat box?

Comment: Seems like a security flaw if you could "inject" random UI events.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to do that. You can't access another app's UI, even with instrumentation.